# dm-postgres-adapter loading error in heroku

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sinatra

I deployed a Sinatra app in Heroku. I am unable to migrate the postgres database because of a dm-postgres-adapter loading error (see below). Any idea how to fix this?

```
irb(main):001:0> require './app'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- dm-postgres-adapter
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:163:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:163:in `load_adapter'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:133:in `adapter_class'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:13:in `new'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core.rb:230:in `setup'
    from /app/app.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1411:in `configure'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1981:in `block (2 levels) in delegate'
    from /app/app.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from (irb):1:in `require'
    from (irb):1
```

My Gemfile:

```
gem 'dm-postgres-adapter', :group => :production
gem 'dm-sqlite-adapter', :group => :development
```

My database configuration within my app main file (app.rb)

```
configure :development do
  DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")
end

configure :production do
  DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
end
```

Comment: Can you share details about your `app.rb`?

Comment: Looks like the `dm-postgres-adapter` gem is not loaded in your app. How are you loading your gems in Sinatra? Try `Bundler.require(:default, ENV['RACK_ENV'])` near the top of `config.ru` file.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles on this:

You need to remove the .bundle/ folder from your working tree, and add .bundle/ to your .gitignore file.

git add/commit/push, then heroku push will solve the problem